# Sending Apple Silent Push Notification using Twilio

Tags: c#, .net-core, twilio, apple-push-notifications

How to set it using twilio notify api SDK for c#?

According to Apple documentation in order to send Silent Push Notification I need to set 3 things:

```
payload: { "aps": "content-available": 1 } }
apns-push-type: background
apns-priority: 5
```

I am trying to achieve it using [NotificationResource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notification-resource) in which I can set payload using `apn`and apns-priority using `priority` to low, but I can't find a way to set `apns-push-type`.

How can I set it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Good news, if you set the `aps` payload to

```
{ "aps": "content-available": 1 }
```

then [Twilio Notify](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify) will automatically add the `apns-push-type: background` to the request to Apple.

I don't believe this is documented anywhere, but I am trying to get that updated.

Comment: Is this actually the case? We're not seeing this behaviour in our current usage.

Comment: @BrandonStillitano I’m not sure what you’re asking. Might be best if you either start a new question and explain what is going on, or, if you think the behaviour is wrong on Twilio’s side, [raise a ticket with support](https://twilio.com/help/contact).